# Can't align (in centre) text inside of div on responsive website when going from pc view to mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, text-alignment

Title says it all, this is my code in html:

```html
 <div id="outline_box">
    <p class="display-2">text</p>
    <pstyle="font-family:'Crimson Text', serif;"> more text</p>
    </div>
```

and this is my css:

```css
#outline_box{
  width: 75%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -37.5%;
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(78, 97, 108, 0.55);
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(78, 93, 102, 0.72);
  font-family: 'Mr De Haviland', cursive;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

It all seems to be working fine on tablets and pcs but on phone-size screens the text gets out of the box towards the right, and thats **totally not right**

*EDIT*
CSS media queries:

```css
/*---Media Queries --*/
@media (max-width: 992px) {
.social a {
    font-size: 4em;
    padding: 2rem;
  }
  }
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.carousel-caption {
    top: 45%;
  }
```

EDIT..again
So, i added some more CSS and it did help a bit with the size of the text and brought it a bit closer to what i wanted but still its not centered. Im still working on it ^^

```css
#outline_box{
      font-size: 140%;
      font-weight: 500%;
      padding-bottom: .2rem;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Have you written any CSS `media query` code to change the content layout for smaller screens? If so then please include this in your question _

Comment: Added Media Queries from my code in the post =)

Comment: does the class `display-2` have any CSS attributes? Also `<pstyle="font-family:'Crimson Text', serif;">` needs a space between `p` & `style=`

Comment: ah right didnt notice that one =P and no, display-2 doesnt have any css attributes, but its some pretty old code im workin on so lemme check again

edit: checked, no, just there for the bootstrap effects.

Comment: You say "bootstrap effects" _ Does this mean you are using Bootstrap? If so please state which version (and possibly add the Bootstrap tag to your question?)

Comment: I am currently working with your code locally _ If you are using Bootstrap please let me know

Comment: Using Bootstrap-4. sorry, forgot to add the tag.

Comment: As screens get smaller so the content of the box (and `#outline_box` itself?) should become smaller, so that everything still fits within the viewing screen _ The @media queries you have included don't adjust for this _ Also, as you're using BS4 why aren't you formulating your code with BS attributes that would  pretty much resolve your responsive issues?

Comment: true. you mean add classes like ``xs-``, ``sm-`` etc? remember about them but imma lookup how they work, havent used bootstrap in a while (havent worked with web-dev in a while in general so im a bit rusty

Comment: added some css (can be seen above) and imma make a quick test to see if it will work, i think im onto something..

Comment: `font-weight` is just a number Nikos, not a percentage, so `font-weight: 500;` _ If you want to centre the text in `#outline_box` adding a new attribute `text-align: center;` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this solution I have taken the basic result of your code but changed the CSS styling substantially to achieve the same thing _

I removed the font attributes from `#outline_box` and put them into separate classes which can be altered with @media queries as required _

I have also simplified the CSS you were using to position `#outline_box` to be more in keeping with the Bootstrap library _ You can see the results in the code snippet below _ and if you put this code into your browser and adjust the screen size you will see the styling adjust to fit _

You can adjust the font-sizes in the classes I created to suit your needs

I hope this helps but I would suggest you brush up on how to use Bootstrap to position and resize the elements on your page _ Good Luck : )

CSS

```
#outline_box {
  background-color: rgba(78, 97, 108, 0.55);
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(78, 93, 102, 0.72);
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15%;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
  width: 75%;
}

.largeText {
  font-family: 'Mr De Haviland', cursive;
  font-size: 6em;
}

.smallText {
    font-family:'Crimson Text', serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {

    .social a {
        font-size: 4em;
        padding: 2rem;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

    .largeText { font-size: 3em;}

    .carousel-caption {
        top: 45%;
    }
}
```

```css
 #outline_box {
   background-color: rgba(78, 97, 108, 0.55);
   border-radius: 20px;
   border: 1px solid rgba(78, 93, 102, 0.72);
   color: white;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 15%;
   text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
   width: 75%;
 }
 
 .largeText {
   font-family: 'Mr De Haviland', cursive;
   font-size: 6em;
 }
  
 .smallText {
  font-family:'Crimson Text', serif;
  font-size: 1em;
 }
 
 @media (max-width: 992px) {
  
  .social a {
   font-size: 4em;
   padding: 2rem;
  }
    }

 @media (max-width: 768px) {
  
  .largeText { font-size: 3em;}
 
  .carousel-caption {
   top: 45%;
  }
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  
  <body>
 
   <div id="outline_box">
    <p class="largeText">text</p>
    <p class="smallText"> more text</p>
   </div>

  </body>
</html>
  

 
 <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```